# Delphi Single near value

Tags: delphi, matrix, scaling, floating-accuracy

so i need to fit a TRectF into another TRectF and get Scale Factor, but all stored in a Single variable.
The problem is that i lost precision, so how i can get nearest down value can be stored in single?

Example:

```
LToFit := TRectF.Create( 0, 0, 320, 480 );

LRect := TRectF.Create( 0, 0, 841, 613 );

LRatio := Min(
  LRect.Width / LToFit.FWidth,
  LRect.Height / LToFit.FHeight
);

// The value of LRatio is 1.27708327770233

// Now i want that result is Pixel aligned so 

LAdd.X := Floor( LToFit.FWidth * LRatio ) mod 2;
LAdd.Y := Floor( LToFit.FHeight * LRatio ) mod 2;

if LRect.Width > LRect.Height then 
  LRatio := ( Floor( LToFit.FWidth * LRatio ) + LAdd.X  ) / FViewer.FView.FWidth
else
  LRatio := ( Floor( LToFit.FHeight * LRatio ) + LAdd.Y ) / FViewer.FView.FHeight;

// The value of LRatio is 1.27499997615814
```

Ecc ... the result is accettable. But now suppose that LRect have -3 in Height so:

```
LToFit := TRectF.Create( 0, 0, 320, 480 );

LRect := TRectF.Create( 0, 0, 841, 610 );

LRatio := Min(
  LRect.Width / LToFit.FWidth,
  LRect.Height / LToFit.FHeight
);

// The value of LRatio is 1.27083337306976

// Now i want that result is Pixel aligned so 

LAdd.X := Floor( LToFit.FWidth * LRatio ) mod 2;
LAdd.Y := Floor( LToFit.FHeight * LRatio ) mod 2;

if LRect.Width > LRect.Height then 
  LRatio := ( Floor( LToFit.FWidth * LRatio ) + LAdd.X  ) / FViewer.FView.FWidth
else
  LRatio := ( Floor( LToFit.FHeight * LRatio ) + LAdd.Y ) / FViewer.FView.FHeight;

// The value of LRatio is 1.26874995231628
```

Ecc ... So in the first case LRatio is 1.27499997615814 for 613 heigh, in second case LRatio is 1.26874995231628 for 610 Heigh.

Other test:

LRatio           Height

A 1.27499997615814 611

B 1.26874995231628 610 <- not accettable

C 1.26874995231628 609 <- not accettable

D 1.26874995231628 608 <- not accettable

E 1.26250004768372 607

The question is how i can restrict LRatio for B and C into A and D into E?
There are other formulas?

All this is to set the Matrix Scaling that uses variables of single type.

Thanks.

UPDATE:

i try to this:

```
S1 := 0;
S2 := 1 / Power( 2, 23 );
while S1 < LRatio do
begin
  S1 := S1 + 0.0625 + S2;
end;
LRatio := S1 - S2;
```

Seems work but i don't know why! Is also more expensive calculation :(

UPDATE 2:

Ok so, without use LAdd i calculate for LRect Height from 605 to 619. How you can see i need only the yellow value. But i can't fond formula:

( Dest Height ): ( Scale ) ( ToFit Scaled Height (Rounded) ) ( Rounded Result H:W )

[image]

SOLUTION ? :

I could not find something more "mathematical" and I'll settle for this function which I think meets what I need.
I would still be grateful for suggestions.

```
function GetRoundedScale( const ARect, AIntoRect: TRectF ): Single;
  var
    LScaled: TPointF;
    LOffSet: Integer;
  begin
    Result := Min(
      AIntoRect.Width / ARect.Width,
      AIntoRect.Height / ARect.Height
    );
    LScaled := TPointF.Create( ARect.Width * Result, ARect.Height * Result );
    LOffSet := 0;
    while Odd( Round( LScaled.X ) ) or Odd( Round( LScaled.Y ) ) do
    begin
      Inc( LOffSet );
      Result := Min(
        ( AIntoRect.Width + LOffSet ) / ARect.Width,
        ( AIntoRect.Height + LOffSet ) / ARect.Height
      );
      LScaled := TPointF.Create( ARect.Width * Result, ARect.Height * Result );
    end;
  end;
```

Comment: What LAdd is doing here? What is purpose of code which computes LRatio for the second time?

Comment: Calculate the ratio I check if the result is equal climbed in order to hit with a division by 2 and is an integer

Comment: What is type of LAdd variable? If it is also single, maybe you should use FMod instead? Also there is Frac() function which returns fractional part of floating-point number. In your implementation LAdd.X and LAdd.Y are either 0 or 1, is it what you want?

Comment: Sure, for example if the Result Height is 310 the mod return 0 so ( 310 + 0 ) / 2 = 155, and if Result Height is 311 the mod return 1 so ( 311 + 1 ) / 2 =  156 instead undesuderable value of 155, 5

Comment: I apologize but I did not understand what you mean: D I do not understand English very well, be clear (simple)

Comment: Ok, I made your picture visible, and your text "(Dest Height):..." got hidden at that time. I returned the text just now.

Comment: Now i understand :D thx

Comment: You don't need to do any floating point here

Comment: In what way are some of these values not acceptable? Too high, too low, what exactly?

Comment: I need obatin scale for have result value divisible by 2.
With the function GetRoundedScale that i have posted, i get this results each 6 pixels.

Comment: You are not making a lot of sense. I still cannot see any reason for floating point.

Comment: Always write these comments on all? I do not know English very well, but an expert could perhaps suggest how to calculate the value of the mantissa of singles to get as close as possible, rather than complimentary comments, but thanks of appreciation

Comment: If instead of writing try using the code posted to draw a rectangle by setting the matrix of the canvas, perhaps you would notice that what I want, is just to design it without blur effect.

Comment: My point is that you should be trying to solve pixel oriented problems with integer arithmetic

Comment: It's really easy to find the nearest single precision value to another value. And if you would do some research you'd find out how to do it. But what I'm telling you is that it isn't the right way to tackle your problem.

Comment: thanks, your help has been of tremendous help